# Snowflake scripting - loop cursor and insert record into table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cursor, sql-insert

I am storing a select query in a resultset.  I then loop the result set with a cursor.  In my for loop is there a way I can insert the current record in a table. I dont wan to use INSERT INTO table (column1) values ('test').

I want to do it like INSERT INTO table(A) select * from record in cursor.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible:

```
DECLARE
    c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT col1, col2 FROM tab_src;
     
    col1 INT;
    col2 INT;
BEGIN
  FOR record IN c1 DO
      col1 := record.col1;
      col2 := record.col2;
  
      INSERT INTO tab_target(A,B)
      SELECT :col1, :col2;
  END FOR;
             
  RETURN 'End';
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am aware of declaring the columns as variables but I want a select * because each table is different I will be doing the insert into.  so I dont know the columns but I want to insert every column into the table from the select *